# WPF - How to prevent keyboard focus transfer to a user control that is clicked by the mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-focus

I have a MyToggleButton user control that inherits from System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton.

If keyboard focus is on another control, and I left-mouse click the MyToggleButton, the keyboard focus is transferred to the MyToggleButton control.

Is there a way that I can prevent the keyboard focus transfer if the MyToggleButton is left-mouse clicked?

**NOTE: the user must still be able to Tab to the MyToggleButton control, which would set the keyboard focus to it.  I just don't want the user to be able to set keyboard focus to it via a left-mouse click.**

Again, the control needs to be clickable via a left-mouse click. I DO NOT want the control to have keyboard focus after it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ToggleButton`'s [Focusable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.focusable?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property to false.

```
Focusable="False"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please see the NOTE that I added above.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your control insensitive to mouse input by setting `HitTestVisible` to false or by consuming the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event and marking it as handled. Both ways have the side effect that mouse interaction is partially or fully inhibited for the control. Using the event handler you still can do right-clicks. Keyboard nav and input however is not effected and still functional.
Here is an example how it works with Textboxes. You can step through all 4 textboxes with TAB, but you can not select the 2nd and 3rd with the left mouse, the 3rd however is responsive to right-mousebutton-clicks.
The focused textbox always appears in lightly red background for demo purpose.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppDummy1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FEFE"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF88" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF8" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox>Hi</TextBox>
        <TextBox IsHitTestVisible="False">Hello</TextBox>
        <TextBox PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">Howdy</TextBox>
        <TextBox>Hey Ho</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

And that's the eventhandler (stub):

```
// C# code behind 
 private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { e.Handled = true; }
```

Comment: As stated in the description, the control needs to be clickable via a left-mouse. I just don't want the keyboard focus to change to this control when it is clicked.

Comment: Kind of bizarre that you change your note anytime someone responds to its current version. Maybe you should find out first what you actually want. In the last version you said it shall *not react to left mouse click*, only to keyboard, Now you want the opposite and reaction on mouse-left-click, while at the same time not getting keyboard focus through the click  - which seems merely impossible, because UIElements that receive and process mouse interaction must have the (keyboard)focus afaics. One can likely just restore the previous focused element post-click, when keeping track of it.

Comment: With all due respect, my description has never changed. I am looking for a way to left-mouse click my control without having the keyboard focus then be applied to the control. I think you are correct, that the only way I can do this is to track the keyboard focus element, and restore it to the previous element when my control is left-mouse clicked.  Thank you very much for your help.